# Primary extensions of a field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

An extension $L$ of a field $k$ is called primary if the relative algebraic closure of $k$ in $L$ is purely inseparable over $k$.

I'm looking for a proof of the following proposition which is used in EGA.
It refers to the Cartan-Chevalley seminar, but I don't have an easy access to it.

**EGA IV-2 (4.3.2)**
Let $K, L$ be extensions of a field $k$.
Suppose $L$ is a primary extension of $k$.
Then $Spec(L\otimes_k K)$ is irreducible and the residue field $\kappa(\xi)$ of the generic point $\xi$ of $Spec(L\otimes_k K)$ is a primary extension of $K$.

Conversely if $Spec(L\otimes_k K)$ is irreducible for every finite separable extension $K$ of $k$,
$L$ is a primary extension of $k$.

Comment: If no one will post a solution, I can give you some hints coming from the Cartan-Chevalley seminar.

Comment: @YACP Thanks. Could you give us a full proof? I think the question is interesting and important not only for me.

Comment: I don't have a proof of my own (actually I'm not interested in this, I simply wanted to help you) and the original proof of Cartier seems to be long enough. But let's wait for a while, maybe someone will post an answer.

Comment: @YACP OK. Let's wait for a while. And if no one would post an answer, please give us hints. Thank you.

Comment: Here's the file that EGA refers to for the proof (more precisely, it refers to pages 03-06): http://numdam.org/numdam-bin/fitem?id=SHC_1955-1956__8__A14_0